# Creating Python bindings for a large quantity of C++ Qt Libraries

Tags: python, c++, qt, binding, python-bindings

**Question in short:**
Do you maybe know, or have any idea how I could implement the **below mentioned**, existing libraries in `Python`, whether that be through bindings or any other possible solution?

---

**Description:**

I'm working on a project and I have a very **large quantity** of **custom built**, **fast-changing** `C++ Qt Libraries` (version 5.15.2) that I need to use in `Python`.

I have done a lot of research on the topic over the past few weeks. However I can't seem to find a suitable solution on how to perform the bindings in an appropriate way.

I have mainly researched `Shiboken`, as that is the python bindings solution that the `Qt Framework` officially supports and encourages.

However `Shiboken` requires me to handwrite a *type-system* and header file for each library with each method or required part of that library that I want to use in my bindings. This is an issue for me as I require every method that is present in the `C++` version to be present in the `Python` version, and hand writing that file is practically impossible.

They will need to be called from Python scripts as any other library would, or in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

`Shiboken` could be a good choice. Yes, you need to specify each class/struct/enum/namespace in a *type-system* and *header file*. But not each method. If you specify a class in a `type-system` file, all the class methods will be extracted to `Python`. For example, this definition is enough:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<typesystem package="mylibrary">
    <object-type name="MyClass1"/>
    <object-type name="MyClass2"/>
</typesystem>
```

Also, you can look at [`PySide`](https://github.com/pyside/pyside-setup) sources. There is a big amount of `Qt` libraries extracted to `Python`. Good example.